# Camunda Authorization with Spring Security and JWT

Tags: camunda

I am using the camunda spring-boot-starter and running the embedded camunda engine.

For Authentication, we are using a JWT token and the user information exists in an outside database. From Camunda docs, what I understood is that, for Camunda Authorization like assigning A User Task to a user, will totally depend on the Camunda Database.

How should I use an outside user authenticated with an external system, for the Authorization purpose in the Camunda? Should I create a copy of the authenticated user in the Camunda Database?

Comment: If the answer answers your question, please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of the authentication you can also tell Camunda which groups/roles the user belongs to. For instance as shown in this generic simple Spring Security example: https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/springboot-security-sso
specifically: https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/blob/4a609b375c6564838e85a1bde7d70e5a9951ab64/snippets/springboot-security-sso/src/main/java/com/camunda/demo/filter/webapp/SpringSecurityAuthenticationProvider.java#L35

Another mechanism uses a custom identity provider (read-only or writable) as explained here: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/identity-service/#custom-whitelist-for-user-group-and-tenant-ids

It is correct that the default implementation is the database identity service, which uses the engine database for managing users and groups.
However, this is only the case if no alternative identity service implementation is provided. Camunda also provides an LDAP identity service for an LDAP-based user/group repository and you can of course implement your own.

Once you have an authenticated user and user group information for the user, the detailed functional permissions are linked to these groups as shown here: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/webapps/admin/authorization-management/

You don't have to manage users in Camunda and or to sync with another system. If user's authorizations (groups, roles) should be fetched from another system, then use the SPI mentioned above. Either way you don't need to create the users in the Camunda DB. When a request comes in you may set the user and its roles on the IdentityService. In your subsequent API usage the user id and the authorization will be considered (if auth is enabled). If authorizations are disabled, then you only need the user id, not the groups/roles. If you want to provide neither and handle everything in your custom code, then you can just complete task without the user's Id (but won't have the user info in the audit information).

Comment: What if I use Java API of Camunda process engine and write my own REST Controller on top of that. I can use my authentication and authorization and later I can call the underlying service call for the authenticated user? I mean what if I leave the Camunda specific DB as it is with just admin, my authenticated user will directly call the Camunda. Even if I want to assign a User task to my user (which is maintained in an outside system) can I not assign that user a task which will be just a String for Camunda engine and stored in Camunda DB just for the history.

Comment: Yes, you can just set the authenticated user as it is shown in the example: https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/blob/4a609b375c6564838e85a1bde7d70e5a9951ab64/snippets/springboot-security-sso/src/main/java/com/camunda/demo/filter/rest/StatelessUserAuthenticationFilter.java#L39

Task assignment and its enforcement are separated. You filter task via the assignment attributes, but can complete with any user id (if authorization are disabled). If authorizations are enabled then those of the authenticated user are checked before completing the task.

Comment: If you decide to complete all tasks with the same user then you lose auditability and the option to use ootb authorizations on engine level. You can also pass the correct user to your custom REST service and propagate the information to the identity service, as show in the filter example in this comment. You could simple extend the same filter you use for the CAMUNDA API also for your custom API.

Comment: My main concern is User Tasks, which will be assigned to some users and those users are in an outside database and also authenticated by an outside system. I do now want to copy those users in Camunda local database for authorization purposes. I want to use authenticated users and assign user tasks to them through a customer REST API, I guess from there that user which does not exist in Camunda DB, will be just a String denoting the user in the outside system.

Comment: If that String is assigned to a User task and persistent in DB then I will know the user assigned, and at the time of completion, I will again use a custom REST API to ensure that authenticated user coming from the outside system is matching to the user String for the task. Assume I am disabling the Camunda REST API completely and using only Java API to interact with the Camunda engine. For another authorization purpose, I can manage it separately within Camunda DB using webapps. I mean those users do not necessarily exist/in sync with my outside system. Am I missing anything in this scenario?

Comment: add response to bottom of answer